# How to properly translate "Monstrous Universe" phrase into Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I've recently started on developing my own gaming project. Some of the words, proper nouns in particular, are planned to get translated into Latin. The problem is that I'm not native speaker of Latin, and Google Translator or any other kinds of translators can't be trusted really. I've even tried to understand the way "Lewis and Short" dictionary works, but sadly there is no way to translate phrases, only words separately, without case endings or consideration of gender.

I had few attempts on translating the sentence using different translators. The result I got was "Monstrosus Universum". But I'm pretty sure that it was translated wrongly. So that is why I'm here, to ask for a professional help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your attempt is not far off. Adjective and noun have to "agree," which in this case means, since *universum* has neutral gender, that we have to use the neutral version of the adjective too:

> Monstrosum universum

The form *monstrosum* is post-classical, or so claim Messrs. Lewis & Short, whom you have already met. If you prefer classical Latin, that would be *monstruosum* -- not much of a difference.

If you think that sounds too much like someone slapped Latin endings on English words, you could try other words, although from a Latin point of view I see little advantage in that. For example, instead of *monstr(u)osum*, you could say *immane*, but that is often used to talk about monstrous *size*. Since the universe actually is very big, that would probably be understood as "vast universe."

You could also say *universitas* instead of *universum* (careful, it's feminine, so it would require *monstruosa*, or *immanis* for that matter).

Comment: Thank you! I greatly appreciate your help, Sebastian. I've been looking for such a detailed response for a very long time. Glad I found this place. Now it will be much easier to continue the development.

Comment: Actually, I've got one more question regarding this theme. Is it written the same way in medieval Latin as it is written in post-classical Latin? Like, is it still being translated as "Monstrosum universum" in such case?

Comment: @Malum I am no expert on medieval peculiarities, but I think that this would be just the same.